# Awk floating point numbers

Tags: bash, awk

I have a awk script that checks all negative values in a file and change them with abs value.

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="\t"} function abs(x) {return ((x < 0.0) ? -x : x)} { 
  for (column = 1; column <= NF; ++column) { 
    if ($column ~ /[0-9]/ && $column < 0.0) { 
      sub($column, abs($column)) 
    } 
  } 
print 
}'
```

In the file all values are represented as floating point numbers for exemple -1000.0, but after I execute the awk command I get 1000 instead of 1000.0.

Comment: What if you just delete all occurrences of `-` sign? `tr -d '-' <filename`. If you need to maintain formatting, (mainly column number), replace `-` by `<space>`: `tr '-' ' ' < filename`

Comment: I guess that would work too ;)

Comment: @anishsane I guess the issue with that idea is that other non-numerical fields may contain a hyphen. Jerome, perhaps you could show us a representative sample of your input?

Comment: Yes, obviously it can contain non-numeric fields. But if the data is always numeric, then `tr` would be much faster. Depends on OP's input data set...

Comment: Yes, @anishsane solution would work with my data, I only have numeric values and * characters in my file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `mask` on the sub:

```
sub(sprintf("%d",$column), abs($column))
```